# Unable to figure out what's triggering "302 Found" when http is redirected to https

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, centos7, http-status-code-302

I'm working on a Wordpress site. When the http version is redirected to https, it gives **302 Found** notification like this:

```
curl -I http://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 27 Nov 2017 08:33:15 GMT
Server: Apache 
Location: https://www.example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I'm unable to figure out what exactly is triggering this. The .htaccess file has this content:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The first 3 lines above doesn't seem to make any difference whether I keep or remove them.

There are no redirections set up for http to https in *cPanel > Redirects* or via the redirection plugins in Wordpress.

However, the dev site which is an exact copy of the live site doesn't have this issue. When I used **curl** on the dev site, it gave me the **301 Moved Permanently**, which is what I was expecting on the live site:

```
curl -I http://dev.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 27 Nov 2017 08:41:53 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Pingback: http://dev.example.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Mon, 27 Nov 2017 09:41:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Location: https://dev.example.com/
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I don't know where else to look. The site is running in VPS/Centos 7/Apache. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to apache configuration files?

Comment: @DusanBajic You mean the `httpd.conf` file? Yes I do. I looked into it but not sure if there's anything relevant in it. Perhaps I'm not sure what I should be looking at. Can you tell me what I should look for in that file?

Comment: Yes, httpd.conf, or any .conf in conf.d/ folder. Look for `RewriteRule`s or `Redirect`s

Comment: Did you try a cache-busting technique to see if the redirect is cached anywhere? It could be cached somewhere unexpected like a proxy.

Comment: @DusanBajic Thanks for the tip. Like you said, it was indeed the `Redirect` directive in another .conf file. I've posted an answer so this could help other people. Thanks!

Comment: @ClaytonLeis I've had the problem resolved. However, I would like to know how to try a cache-busting technique in this context. Might be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was. It was in the httpd.conf file that had another .conf file included. The included .conf file had a `Redirect` directive in it. When I commented it out, the `RewriteRule` directive in the .htaccess became active.